# How to get event name in GMap V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

How to get event name in GMap V3.

Tried as,

```
function initialize(){

    -------------------
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click',function(){handleViewUpdate();});

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragend", function () {handleViewUpdate();});
    -------------------

}

function handleViewUpdate(){
    alert(map.getEvent()+' Event');
}
```

but fails. :(

Any help please :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you use some flag variable send it as a parameter to the function 
for eg:
handleViewUpdate(1) for first thing
handleViewUpdate(2) for other.
 then you can get the event name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no map method named `getEvent`, but some of the event listener callbacks do pass arguments (but not all). For example, you could change your `click` event listener definition to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function( event ) {
    //do something with the event parameter here
    handleViewUpdate();
});
```

In contrast, the `dragend` event does *not* pass anything to the event listener. The `google.maps.Map`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) has full details if you scroll down to the **Events** table.

All that said, the `google.maps.MouseEvent`[<sup>api-doc</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) doesn't include a "name" or "type" property that could be used to address your specific question. I've inspected the incoming event in Chrome's console and there is nothing that you can use to perform a `switch` action. When you define the event listener, the callback function is about the only thing that you can use to give you the context of the event that was fired. So the suggestion in @NejiHyuga's answer is pretty much your best option.